# Spring MVC modules,subsystems and components

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, architecture

Let's say we have a Spring MVC project which is a banking web application. I am trying to identify the sub-systems ,modules and components of this project.

1.Subsystems - from what I have red the subsystems in MVC architecture are only 3- the Model,View and Controller is that correct?

2.Modules - are these a group of classes that do something particular as a group.For example LoginController.java,RegisterControler.java form a module let's call it Authentication

3.Components - for components I am not sure which they are in a Spring MVC project.

If someone can explain with examples in terms of a banking web application or other Spring MVC app it would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Spring MVC follows the Model-View-Controller design pattern.

**Model -** A model contains the data of the application. A data can be a single object or a collection of objects.

**Controller -** A controller contains the business logic of an application. Here, the @Controller annotation is used to mark the class as the controller.

**View -** A view represents the provided information in a particular format. Generally, JSP+JSTL is used to create a view page. Although spring also supports other view technologies such as Apache Velocity, Thymeleaf and FreeMarker.

Spring Boot Framework has mainly four major Components.

- Spring Boot Starters.
- Spring Boot AutoConfigurator.
- Spring Boot CLI.
- Spring Boot Actuator.

Please check out : https://www.journaldev.com/7989/key-components-and-internals-of-spring-boot-framework

Comment: okay these are the components for Spring boot framework itself , but in terms of a project?

Answer (score 0):

In project-specific terms,

Module: It can be something that can be built separately in an application. ex: Login Module, Sign-up module, Transactions module, etc., You can say a module is a group of components.

Sub-systems: As far as I know, subsystems are the service package related [stuff](https://springframework.guru/gang-of-four-design-patterns/facade-pattern/facade02/).

Components: Annotating a class with @Component tells Spring that it is available for fulfilling injections.

Spring Component annotation is used to denote a class as a Component. It means that the Spring framework will autodetect these classes for dependency injection when annotation-based configuration and classpath scanning is used